# Why is this string being converted to JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have two functions happening on a DragAndDrop type event. When the jqgrid is being initialized:

```
function gridInitialized() {
    var grid = $( this );
    var gridId = grid[0].id;
    var droppableArea = [];
    //Code to populate droppableArea successfully 

    for( var i = 0, len = $( droppableArea ).length; i < len; i++ ) {
        //THIS IS THE LINE IN QUESTION
        $( droppableArea )[i].attr( "ondrop", "return handleDropHtml5( event, " + gridId + " )" );
        //END OF LINE IN QUESTION
    }
}
```

and then the function to handle the drop:

```
function handleDropHtml5( event, gridId ) {
    //Code to handle the drop
}
```

I noticed that I didn't put `gridId` in quotes when I was declaring the attribute `"ondrop"` but thought it might work anyway since the whole part was a string and gridId is a string as well. However when It got to the `handleDropHtml5` the gridId is coming through as a JQuery table of the same name as `gridId`. I don't need a solution to passing the `gridId` correctly, I have that already. I'm curious as to why this conversion is happening. What is causing the JQuery table to appear?

Comment: Why are you using attr to assign an event handler? That is bad practice. Use `.on()`

Comment: @epascarello `attr` was left over from someone else's code and I just needed to add the grid to shift how we were doing things now and didn't want to alter too much.

Comment: [Most?] Browsers will automagically create a global variable for each element's ID!  That's what's happening here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is rendering as

```
<foo ondrop="return handleDropHtml5( event, theId )">
```

so `theId` is being used as a global variable and not a string. Some browsers will see that the id matches and will return the DOM element that matches that id.

You would need to quote the string so it is seen as a string and not an id.

```
$( droppableArea )[i].attr( "ondrop", "return handleDropHtml5( event, '" + gridId + "' )" );
```

BUT you should NOT be using attr to set event handlers. You should be using proper ways to attach an event such as jQuery's `on()`

```
$( droppableArea ).on( "drop", function (event) { return handleDropHtml5( event, gridId ); } );
```